# Connecting to Microsoft Access file at server

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have this `access.mdb` at server folder. My webpage will connect to this access database using :

```
"Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/cloud/login/mydatabase.mdb")
```

so the server path will be `www.abc.com/cloud/login/mydatabase.mdb`.

How can I connect to this database from my computer?
using C# or access

```
string connectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12;DATA SOURCE=www.abc.net/cloud/login/login.mdb;";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
```

I tried connecting to server database using `Access/ExternalData` and point to the server path but I am unable to connect.

Reason why I am doing this is because when I change data, I need to use FTP to download this `.mdb` and change and upload back. Which is very troublesome.

Comment: You need to [share](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2C24EB08-BEE1-453E-BE8E-455F847C5C74?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm3) the folder first.

Does it really have to be Access though? You can [Upsize](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924) to SQL Server, or create a webservice.

Comment: because our current system is all using access.The folder already set to accessible.

Comment: Directory browsing in IIS "Allows users to see the site's directory listing in web browsers, for example, when the default index page is not available. " already on

Comment: You do realize that you're opening a very big hole in your server security just because it's inconvenient for you to FTP a file, right? So when you lose absolutely everything because somebody wipes your site out, you can tell your boss *But I only did it because I was too lazy to FTP my database.*, and see if that works to not get fired.

Comment: is not some important data

Comment: each time we FTP.the whole web will be down.tats y we want a direct connection to modified the data in access

Answer (score 0):

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\serverName\cloud\login\login.mdb;
```

Note: The Server name is where you have ur mdb , so put that name. The folder which u access should be shared for access.